# Problema sobre decimales que no se muestran en la base de datos ASP.NET CORE6

Tags: asp.net-core, formato, .net-6.0, decimal

espero me puedan ayudar, he creado un modelo de prueba y en la parte de Monto que debería enviar valores decimales, no los envia, solo agrega los ceros, pero no los decimales, por ejemplo envío 45.66 y en la base de datos recibo 4566.00, envio los codigos.

Este es el modelo TestingPrueba:

```
namespace ProyectoVircorCoreFinal.Models
{
    public class TestingPrueba
    {
        [Key]
        public int idTest { get; set; }


        /*---id RUC------------------------*/
        [Required]
        public string idRuc { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("idRuc")]
        public RazonSocial RazonSocialNombres { get; set; }
        /*---------------------------------*/


        [Required]        
        [Display(Name = "Monto")] 
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]        
        public decimal Monto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Este es el controlador "TestingPrueba";

```
// GET: TestingPruebas/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["idRuc"] = new SelectList(_context.RazonSociales, "idRUC", "RazonSocialNombres");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: TestingPruebas/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("idTest,idRuc,Monto")] TestingPrueba testingPrueba)
        {                         
            
                _context.Add(testingPrueba);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));            
         
        }
```

En la base de datos sqlserver, el formato de la columna Valor es : decimal(10,2)
No entiendo que podria estar pasando.

Comment: Y como lo estas guardando? porque lo importante es eso... ademas, puede que tengas un temita muy importante con el signo de decimales.. usas . o ,???

Comment: Lo guardo como decimal, ose escribo 34.50 con punto, pero me envía a la base de datos como 345.00.

Comment: no. Como es el codigo que usas para guardarlo??? como ves el numero en el debug? en definitiva, tu separador decimal no es el punto, y de ahi viene tu problema...

Comment: En esta linea `_context.Add(testingPrueba);` coloca un punto de interrupción y verifica el monto que trae `testingPrueba`. Porque yo creo que el problema está en el parse que hace .net al POST y no en lo que se guarda en la BD

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, encontré el problema, la razón de que no consideraba los decimales, era la configuración de formato decimal de mi PC, ahora esta normal.